# How can I get data from SQL via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a problem with my school project.
I have a form where I post data to SQL database (name, age, city) - This is OK
How can I do, when I post data, I will show it in next php site (after confirm)?
Data from post.php to show.php?id=xxx (where ID is ID of user)...
In show.php I want to show data as name, age, city from user´s ID and link to show.php?id=xxx
Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: Your question is more like rambling. Please post some code you have tried and what error you are getting. Though I feel you are looking for $_SESSION variables

Answer (score 1):

First pull the id out of the get parameter:

`$id = $_GET["id"]`

Then execute a select query. Something like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT age, name, city FROM student WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($age, $name, $city);
$stmt->fetch();
// now $age, $name and $city are set with the values from mySql
```